# Ubuntu Server 18.04.6: No internet connection

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, internet, netplan

My Ubuntu 18.04.6 server is not connecting to the wider LAN and Internet. It IS connecting to my router (via ethernet cable), which is connected to by many other household devices (wired and wireless) without issue.

My router identifies the device as connected with the correct MAC address and IP address.
My server identified the IP address as the gateway using ip a.

The netplan "01-netcfg.yaml" is as follows:

```
network:
   version: 2
   renderer: networkd
   ethernets:
      enp0s25:
         dhcp4: no
         addresses: [192.168.0.12/24]
         gateway4: 192.168.0.100
         nameservers:
            addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
```

This has been validated using netplan --debug apply (after generating).

Pinging any address (including google, any nameserver, and the gateway) results in 100% packet loss.

I am now at a loss over how to proceed.

Apologies, I would include more output, but I have to manually type it due to only being able to access the server directly and not remotely via SSH.

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify, the static IP address is not being allocated to any other devices on the router, but I have reserved the address on that side anyway, and restarted the server, without success.

[screenshot of router server address allocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Indbj.png)

Comment: Are you **sure** your router is not assigning address 192.168.0.12 to another device via DHCP?

Comment: @steeldriver I agree with steeldriver. I often have to set the static IP in my router when using a static IP on any device. That is, I have to set the static IP on both the device ***and*** the router.

Comment: I can confirm no other device is using that IP address on the router. However, I did reserve the address through that as well to be sure, then restarted the server. Nothing changed :-(

I have also tried enabling DHCP4 as well before to see if the static IP address setting was causing the problem. It wasn't. I'll edit my post.